# How use NSPredicate with array contains Contact object

Tags: ios, uitableview, nspredicate, segue

after full research, I don't find a solution to my problem. 
I have a tableview wich contains object of Contact. This contact have name,mobile,street ...

My problem is :
 when I make a search , I want to search about name of contact. For the moment I make a research about String value

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchText];
```

It s work perfectly , but now, I won't make my research with names of contacts. How can I proceed ? 
**When I put that :**

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@",searchText];
```

I have an error :

```
erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x8d76100> valueForUndefinedKey:]: <br/><br/>this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.' .
```

In my class Contact I have  :

```
@property NSString * name;
@property NSString * display_name;
@property NSString * phone;
@property NSString * mobile;
```

Someone can tell step by step how make a research with an nsmutablearray that contains ojetcs ?

Comment: Does the array you are trying to filter have `Contact` objects? Seems like the array have elements of type `NSString`. Check the array.

Comment: You need to drill further down. are the objects in the array 'Contact' objects ?

Comment: Yes , I have array of contact : [contactSearch addObject:myContact];

Comment: @Mcr67 can you show the code where you used `resultPredicate`?

Comment: - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchText];    
 searchResults = [contactSearch filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try:

```
 NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", searchText];
 NSArray *temp = [YOUR_ARRAY filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate]; ?
```

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[YOUR_ARRAY enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    Contact *contact = obj;

    if ([[contact name] isEqualToString:searchText])
        [searchResults addObject:contact];
}];

//The search results array should now contain the matching items:
NSLog(@"Search Results:%@", searchResults);
```

Comment: I have this error erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Contact copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e613d0'

Comment: Is contact the objects in your array ?

Comment: Yes it is. I have [contactSearch addObjetc:myContact];

Comment: What type of object is it ?

Comment: I have a Contact Class that contains name,mobile etc... And I create a contact and add to my mutablearray

Comment: So it's just an NSObject ?

Comment: Yes . Sorry, I have @interface Contact : NSObject

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
 NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@ OR display_name contains[cd] OR phone contains[cd] OR mobile contains[cd]", searchText];
```

Comment: Simple, for a CloudKit record contains predicate example:  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myArray contains %@", cloudKitReference];

Answer (score 2):

Using Predicates with Arrays

NSArray and NSMutableArray provide methods to filter array contents. NSArray provides filteredArrayUsingPredicate: which returns a new array containing objects in the receiver that match the specified predicate. NSMutableArray provides filterUsingPredicate: which evaluates the receiver’s content against the specified predicate and leaves only objects that match.

```
NSMutableArray *array =
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nick", @"Ben", @"Adam", @"Melissa", nil];

NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'a'"];
NSArray *beginWithB = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
// beginWithB contains { @"Adam" }.

NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'e'"];
[array filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
// array now contains { @"Nick", @"Ben", @"Melissa" }
```

If you use the Core Data framework, the array methods provide an efficient means of filtering an existing array of objects without—as a fetch does—requiring a round trip to a persistent data store.

Here [**LINK**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) for Details